# Unable to iterate over an ElementArrayFinder

Tags: javascript, typescript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm a beginner writing e2e Javascript tests using Protractor. I have been trying to identify an array of elements that have a text property associated with them. I'm able to target them using

`groupedNodeNumbers : ElementArrayFinder;`

`this.groupedNodeNumbers = this.element.all(by.css(".side-label-background + .side-label"));`

This is supposed to give me an array of elements on which I can call getText() to extract the value associated with each of them.

```
validateCountGraphNodes = async() => {
        let count = 0;
        console.log('Inside')
        this.groupedNodeNumbers.each((groupedNodeElement) => {
            groupedNodeElement.getText().then((num) => {
            console.log('Inside loop')
                count += parseInt(num, 10);
                console.log(count);
            });
        });
}`
```

I am able to log ('Inside') but not ('Inside Loop') and hence my function fails to retrieve the text associated with each element.

Could someone please point where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: Please show the error message of `getText()`.  Two issues in your code, 1)  should remove `this` from `this.element.all()`,  generally `element` is global. 2)  `.side-label-background + .side-label` should only return one element, thus your function should always return 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `getText()` applied returns string instead of an array of strings (existing issue), you can try the following:

```
const cssSelector = ".side-label-background + .side-label";


$$(cssSelector).getText().then(textArrNotArr => {
    for(let i = 0; i< textArrNotArr.lenght; i++) {
        console.log('arr[i] = ', textArrNotArr[i]);
    }
});
```

or

```
$$(cssSelector).count().then(elFinderArray => {
    elFinderArray.forEach(elFinder => {
        elFinder.getText().then((txt, index) => {
            console.log(index);
        });
    });
});
```

note: `$$('cssSelector')` can be used instead of `element.all(by.css('cssSelector'))`